# how to include a url parameter inside a url parameter (It considers the nested parameter as parameter of the original request)

Tags: javascript, html, url-parameters

I wish to pass a url like :

```
localhost:9090/admin/GroupInfo.action?message=redirect.jsp?sop=here&something=other
```

I want to receive "`redirect.jsp?sop=here&something=other`" as the value of the parameter "`message`", but I only get "`redirect.jsp?sop=here`" at the server. It probably treats sop as another parameter for the parent url. How to avoid that ?

I tried escaping the second `'&'` by replacing it with `&amp;` but it didn't work

Comment: You will need to use percent-url-encoding instead of html encoding, so use `%26`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [encoreURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

```
encodeURIComponent("redirect.jsp?sop=here&something=other");
```